# Spliting a string using a regular expression returns a collection with a single element

Tags: arrays, regex, kotlin

I'm newbie and i'm trying to create an app to check a string that represents a bus ticket.
I have a problem with this function but i don't know what it is.

```
    fun mostrarBilhete(){
        strMostraBilhete = "Automacao\n" +
                "Saiba mais em: \n"+
                "www.exemploautomacao.com.br\n"+
                "--------------------------------\n"+
                "Demo  Venda Passagem\n"+
                "--------------------------------\n"
        val arr = Pattern.compile("\\|").split(strTxtLido)
        Log.i("TESTE txtLido", strTxtLido)
        Log.i("TESTE arr", arr.contentToString())

        strMostraBilhete+= buildString {
        append("--------------------------------\n")
        append("Origem:")
        append(arr[0].toString())
        append("  ")
        append("Destino: ")
        append(arr[1].toString())
        append("\nData: ")
        append(arr[2].toString())
        append(" |")
        append(arr[3].toString())
        append("\n")
        append("(Poltrona: ")
        append(arr[4].toString())
        append(" Plataforma 1)\n")
        append("--------------------------------\n")
        append("Tarifa:                   130.00\n")
        append("Valor a Pagar:            130.00\n")
        append("\nFORMA DE PAGAMENTO VALOR PAGO R$\n")
        append("Dinheiro                  150.00\n")
        append("Troco                      20.00\n\n")
        append("Consulte pela chave de acesso em\n")
        append("www.exemploautomacao.com.br")
        append("\n0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000\n\n")
        append("Passageiro: ")
        append("DOC 0000000000 - \n")
        append(arr[5].toString())
        append("\nData de autorizacao: ")
        append(arr[6].toString())
    }
```

whenever I run this fucntion the app crashs
the logcat shows this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                                                         
  at br.com.example.passagem.MainActivity2.mostrarBilhete

  ...
```

I dont know what is wrong, I'm new into kotlin

If any information is missing i'll edit this,

Comment: Seems your `split` does return an array with only one element ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Kotlin, you might as well use the tools it provides. In particular, instead of using Java's `Pattern`, use Kotlin's [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/) .

Now consider the scenario when `strTxtLido` does not contain the `|` character. In this case `split()` will return a list of size one (just the original string) and trying to access a value beyond index 0 will trigger an out-of-bounds exception.

This code will allow you to experiment with various inputs:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val regexp = Regex("""\|""")
    val strings = listOf("abcd", "a|bcd", "ab|c|d", "abcd|")

    strings.onEach { str ->
        regexp.split(str)
            .also { println("split($str) = $it (size=${it.size})") }
    }
}
```

It is for you to decide how to handle the scenario where the input has unexpected number of `|`. One option is to fail explicitly with an `IllegalStateException`:

```kotlin
    val splits  =  regexp.split("a|b|c|d|ef")
    check(splits.size == 6) {"Unexpected input. The number of splits was ${splits.size}"}
```